# Как сохранить данные в рекурсивной функции?

Tags: python

Всем здравствуйте! Написал функцию для реализации перестановок при помощи рекурсии, где `number_len` - количество позиций для подстановки, `n=10` по умолчанию для системы счисления (грубо говоря).

```
def generate_numbers(number_len, n=10, prefix=[]):
    if number_len == 0:
        print(prefix)
        return
    else:
        for k in range(n):
            prefix.append(k)
            generate_numbers(number_len - 1, n, prefix)
            prefix.pop()
```

Захотелось немного модифицировать функцию и сохранить все списки, которые мне выдаются принтом.

```
import pickle

file = open('data', 'wb')

def perm(number_len, n=10, prefix=[]):
    if number_len == 0:
        print(prefix)
        pickle.dump(prefix, file)
        return
    else:
        for k in range(n):
            prefix.append(k)
            perm(number_len - 1, n, prefix)
            prefix.pop()

perm(3)
file.close()

file = open('data', 'rb')
data = pickle.load(file)
print(data, type(data))
file.close()
```

В итоге выводит лишь один массив перестановки.
Подскажите, как можно вообще получить данные из рекурсивной функции?  Может есть способ сделать это и без `pickle`?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Ваш код выводит все различные комбинации, так что `В итоге выводит лишь один массив перестановки`  - неправда.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно превратить вашу функцию в генератор. Ну а дальше, хотите - итерируйтесь в цикле, хотите - сохраняйте варианты в список.

```
def generate_numbers(number_len, n=10, prefix=[]):
    if number_len == 0:
        yield prefix.copy()
    else:
        for k in range(n):
            prefix.append(k)
            yield from generate_numbers(number_len - 1, n, prefix)
            prefix.pop()

lst = list(generate_numbers(2))
print(lst)
#for v in generate_numbers(2):
#    print(v)
```

```
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4], [0, 5], [0, 6], [0, 7], [0, 8], [0, 9], 
 [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5], [1, 6], [1, 7], [1, 8], [1, 9], 
 [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3], [2, 4], [2, 5], [2, 6], [2, 7], [2, 8], [2, 9], 
 [3, 0], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3], [3, 4], [3, 5], [3, 6], [3, 7], [3, 8], [3, 9], 
 [4, 0], [4, 1], [4, 2], [4, 3], [4, 4], [4, 5], [4, 6], [4, 7], [4, 8], [4, 9], 
 [5, 0], [5, 1], [5, 2], [5, 3], [5, 4], [5, 5], [5, 6], [5, 7], [5, 8], [5, 9], 
 [6, 0], [6, 1], [6, 2], [6, 3], [6, 4], [6, 5], [6, 6], [6, 7], [6, 8], [6, 9],
 [7, 0], [7, 1], [7, 2], [7, 3], [7, 4], [7, 5], [7, 6], [7, 7], [7, 8], [7, 9],
 [8, 0], [8, 1], [8, 2], [8, 3], [8, 4], [8, 5], [8, 6], [8, 7], [8, 8], [8, 9],
 [9, 0], [9, 1], [9, 2], [9, 3], [9, 4], [9, 5], [9, 6], [9, 7], [9, 8], [9, 9]]
```

---

Но, по-хорошему, полагаться на побочный эффект списка параметра по-умолчанию я бы не стал. И переписал бы генератор так:

```
def generate_numbers(number_len, n=10, prefix=[]):
    if number_len == 0:
        yield prefix
    else:
        for k in range(n):
            yield from generate_numbers(number_len - 1, n, prefix + [k])
```

---

Если хотите обойтись без генератора, то функция должна возвращать результат и, накапливая, аккуратно поднимать его назад по рекурсии.

```
def generate_numbers(number_len, n=10, prefix=[]):
    if number_len == 0:
        result = [prefix]
    else:
        result = []
        for k in range(n):
            result.extend(generate_numbers(number_len - 1, n, prefix + [k]))
    return result
```